# Android and IOS web socket server

Tags: android, ios, websocket, server

I've seen some stackover flow questions and answer that imply this could be possible but I don't have a straight yes or no to this therefore posting this question.

Basically I just want to know if I run an application from both android and IOS which is coded in something like React Native, And then run a websocket server with the WS lib? and if I did that would it just work without having to open ports and things or any other special set ups?

Comment: Way too broad to answer shortly. A websocket server in the mobile app? Or somewhere else? What connects to it?

Comment: well basically yes. A js based application like react native and i run the ws server library. n I retrieve the ip address. Can i then run from my browser and then access that ip:port like I could with a regular server?

Comment: and would it work on both IOS and Android?

Comment: the idea is a phone would connect to an aws server which would be an amazon lambda function, we would execute multiple asynchronous executions and then the asynchronous task would then connect to the device and send a success or erroneous response back to the device for real time results